# How to protect my PC against a guest's usb flash drives?

Tags: security, usb-flash-drive

I am having a guest who would like to use my PC (Windows 10 Home). Recommend a solution how to protect my PC from potential malware threats from his USB flash drive.

Note I do not care at all if the guest catches any malware from my PC, that his problem to protect his drive.

I hope the guest would not intentionally run any software from his drive, yet he might need to access his documents.

So far I only disabled autoplay. I think I have an old Windows 8 laptop with installed "USB drive security" suite or something, I think I can lend it to the guest. After guest leaves, I will run antivirus or just backup important data and reinstall windows.

Comment: Due to flaws in USB implementation, a device can identify itself as *anything*, including a keyboard, and enter malware. https://medium.com/bugbountywriteup/how-i-made-a-programmable-hacking-usb-device-to-infiltrate-pcs-449726c5b23d Other than fill all USB ports with epoxy, there's little you can do if someone has physical access.

Comment: @slhck did you read the question? I am protecting my PC against a USB drive threats not USB drives.

Comment: "he would like access his documents." Buy a new USB. Copy the documents for him. He cannow go to another place and access his documents.

Comment: Yeah, I got that reversed. Your question was quite vague though in its first revision.

Comment: Could you advice me what was vague in the first edition, so I will try be more clear next time "Having a guest who would like use my PC (Windows 10 Home). Recommend a solution how prevent virus transfer from his USB flash drive."

Comment: @Serge - The only way to avoid malicious malware on a storage device is to never connect a storage device you don't trust to the machine.

Answer (score 4):

The good news is that Windows 10 will no longer let any software execute
automatically from the USB whenever it is plugged in. This "feature"
was also called Autorun.

The bad news is that if your friend executes any software from the USB,
and that software is infected, it may also infect your own computer.

If you would prefer the computer to stay in its exact current state as from
before your friend started working on it, you may use the new  Windows Sandbox
to place the computer into a state where all changes are discarded when
going off this mode.

This would mean that your friend can work on files on his USB, may even copy them
to hard disk, but will need to take it away with him on the USB.
Once the  Windows Sandbox is closed, this will
undo whatever changes he did to Windows and the hard disk.

For more information, see the articles:

- [How to Use Windows 10’s New Sandbox (to Safely Test Apps)](https://www.howtogeek.com/399290/how-to-use-windows-10s-new-sandbox-to-safely-test-apps/)
- [Windows Sandbox](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-Kernel-Internals/Windows-Sandbox/ba-p/301849)

Third-party products in this area are:

- [Toolwiz Time Freeze](http://www.toolwiz.com/lead/toolwiz_time_freeze.php)
- [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/)

Comment: Is Windows Sandbox feature still restricted to Pro and Enterprise versions?

Comment: @fred_dot_u - Yes;   Windows Sandbox would not be helpful in a case like this.

Comment: Forgot about Home. You may have a look at the free [Toolwiz Time Freeze](http://www.toolwiz.com/lead/toolwiz_time_freeze.php) or [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/).

Comment: I would not trust that Windows Sandbox or Sandboxie would protect you from the type of malware that infests a flash storage device.

Comment: @Ramhound Sandboxie would if it's configured correctly, however it's one of the most user un-friendly pieces of software I've ever come across due to its complete lack of thorough/advanced documentation on how to correctly configure it for whatever enironment the user has.

Comment: @harrymc I don't believe Windows Sandbox can be utilized to sandbox USB drives or storage mediums in general.  I could very well be wrong, but due to the Sandbox being a Hyper-V VM that isn't available from within Hyper-V Manager, there's no way to attach storage to it (unless it's possible via PowerShell).  Even if it was available, the user must manually offline the drive after it's already been accessed by Windows.  Once offlined, Windows won't online the drive again until it's been manually switched online, regardless if the drive has been disconnected & reconnected.

Comment: @JW0914: The point is to sandbox Windows itself, not the USB.

Comment: @harrymc Windows Sandbox doesn't do that either... it's just a VM that allows the execution of downloaded binaries, and AFAIK you can't transfer files from the host to the Sandbox VM nor share/attach host drives to the Sandbox.  Your suggestion of Sandboxie _(a great piece of software)_ is a true sandbox, allowing complete state restoration, but lacks the documentation on how to configure it & has seen very limited community involvement for several years - it's as if the developers never bothered to actually create documentation on how to effectively utilize it _(at least as of 2 years ago)_.

Comment: @JW0914: The UI of Sandboxie seemed clear enough to me, and the documentation is enough to clarify points which are not evident. My personal opinion only, of course.

Comment: curiously, I found recipes to disable Win 10 autoplay and autorun (for Prof version) e.g https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-disable-autoplay-and-autorun-in-windows-10/

Comment: @Serge: These are for previous versions of Windows.

Comment: for previous version of Win 10 or 8?

Comment: Probably Windows 10. These options still pertain for CD, DVD, or media cards, but not for USB.

Comment: @harrymc Did you come across a way to attach storage to the VM Sandbox?  If you did, that would be awesome.

Comment: @JW0914: One example is [here](https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/134340-how-get-windows-sandbox-recognize-usb-jump-drives.html).

Comment: @harrymc That's awesome, thanks!  =] With regards to Sandboxie, I bought a license a few years ago and after a month of research on their forum, I was still unable to get Chrome to fully load in Sandboxie w/ extensions working.  AFAIK, there's no documentation from Sandboxie on how to correctly set that up & forum threads regarding browsers were years old at that point and of little help.  With all that being said, it appears Sandboxie was purchased by [Sophos](https://community.sophos.com/products/sandboxie/f/forum) sometime in the last 2 years or so, so the documentation will likely improve.